# cgi.pm redirect does not print to Target _top

Tags: jquery, perl, cgi

I am not sure how much information I need to give here .. so bear with me please while I try to explain the scenario. Apologies if there is too much "padding"

I have an application in which I use CGI::Session for security. The various pages are pulled in with a combination of jquery, perl, ajax calls etc.  When I print one of the password-protected pages I check the logged-in status of the CGI::Session record and redirect to the homepage if necessary with the following perl:

```
print $cgi->redirect( -URL => $homepage);
```

This works perfectly as expected.

However ...

There is a DIV in one of the password-protected pages which contains a control panel ... which was itself pulled in via jquery and an ajax call. I recently decided to add some extra security to the Saving of this data when the user clicks the "ok" ... which invokes another ajax call to perl (ControlPanelSave.pl). In the perl I decided to add the same check for the CGI::Session logged-in flag (the user may have been sitting too long on the control panel and when they click Save they had already timed out - or maybe a bad person had found the javascript).  So the perl checks and redirects to the homepage if not logged in.

The problem I have is that the homepage is then printed inside the Control Panel DIV like it was a frame.

I tried using the only method I could think of to fix it:

```
print $cgi->redirect( -URL => $homepage, -target => '_top' );
```

Which doesn't make any difference - it still prints the homepage inside the control panel DIV.

What is the correct way to redirect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to edit the JavaScript to recognise that it didn't get the data it was expecting and set `location` on the client.

Comment: Do you mean not do the redirect in the perl - but instead, return a flag to the JS and do the redirect there instead? ... ok that sounds ok ... so there is no way to do what I want from the perl?

Comment: Since the response is handled entirely by JavaScript, correct.